# Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation - vscode 2022 (Fixed)

Tags: error-handling, vscode-debugger

I'm writing a game, and when the game executes it pauses and I get this error in olcpixlegamengine.h:

Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
sprite was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

I added some output statements and narrowed it down to once this loop ends:

[image: Code Section]

That function is pulling from the graphics library:

[image: Graphics library function]

Comment: With the (little) information given we can only assume either that `sprTile` is not in fact 20 elements long, or (less likely) that it gets accidentally corrupted by something else.

Comment: Thanks 500 - Internal Server Error. it was 18 elements long, thanks for the help